# Azure App Services File Access

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I've got a few files on wwwroot/uploads which need to be publicly accessible by anyone.

It currently throws a 404 Error, but the file exists, and the URL I'm using is correct. Can anyone guide me to configuring the access controls to this folder?

I've tried using .htaccess files (allow all), and also tried messing with the web.config file. No luck though. (The access attributes need to be applied recursively to all children of the 'uploads' directory.

Thanks all!

Update:

The problem was IIS was not configured to support the .mp4 MIME type I was trying to use. Just added that in there in the main web.config file and it works now :)

Thanks to @misaim for his help :)

Comment: Can you update question to clarify the **extension** of the files you're trying to access? Does it work if you put an html file in there?

Comment: Yeah it was a .mp4 file and the MIME just wasn't configured to work. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to the MIME type not being enabled for media files by default. Try removing the web.config and enabling mp4 or image file and see if your errors go away.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the Systems permissions of the files? Not just the web server permissions? i.e. chmod -R 777 (Don't actually do this, use correct permissions, this is to open).